# I got a overall mean average precision score of 0 for a recommendation engine

Tags: python, recommender-system, pyspark, metric

I just wanted to know if receiving an overall MAP score of 0 in a recommendation engine was possible, or a sign that my calculation or my logic for the engine was wrong.

Comment: what's the number of the possible labels and also the population of your data?

Comment: @AlirezaZolanvari my data is the movie lens dataset the labels would be the rating. So I’m comparing the predicted rating (via an ALS model) and the actual rating (which ranges from 0-5)